# sort box on eccomerce site causing javascript slider to reload each time

Tags: jquery, slider, reload, flicker

I have an image slider at the top of my page below which are my products, the problem is when i sort the products with the select box the page flickers due to the slider reloading and resetting to the first slide. I want the products to be sortable without the slider reloading and resetting to the first slide again? I've read a lot around the subject of flickering but i'm fairly new to javascript and php and i'm still struggling

The code below is from the productlist.php file in which there are 3 includes called up in the body tag, the header, the slider and the product list.

ALSO... for some reason the slider breaks if the two called up scripts at the bottom of the page are placed with the others in the head section. I've no answer as to why this is.

```
?><?php
// GLOBAL INCLUDES 
require_once("Application.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Product Listings | <?php echo $_ENV["request.cwpage"]["title"]; ?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="Description" content="<?php echo ((isset($_ENV["request.cwpage"]["description"])) ? $_ENV["request.cwpage"]["description"] : "" ); ?>">
    <?php // CARTWEAVER CSS ?>
    <!--- START CARTWEVER CORE CSS --->
    <link href="cw4/css/cw-core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--- END CARTWEVER CORE CSS --->   
    <!--- START HEADER CSS --->     
    <link href="cw4/style_sheets/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  
    <!--- END HEADER CSS --->

    <!--- START LINKS FOR PP_slider --->        
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cw4/style_sheets/container_p2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cw4/style_sheets/customer_info_panel.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cw4/style_sheets/slit_slider_style_2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cw4/style_sheets/slit_slider_style_custom_2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cw4/style_sheets/customer_info_panel.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cw4/style_sheets/share_tab_2.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cw4/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cw4/js/modernizr.custom.79639.js"></script>
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cw4/style_sheets/slit_slider_styleNoJS.css" /></noscript>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="cw4/js/jquery.ba-cond.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cw4/js/jquery.slitslider.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function() {

            var Page = (function() {

                var $nav = $( '#nav-dots > span' ),
                    slitslider = $( '#slider' ).slitslider( {
                        onBeforeChange : function( slide, pos ) {

                            $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                            $nav.eq( pos ).addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );

                        }
                    } ),

                    init = function() {

                        initEvents();

                    },
                    initEvents = function() {

                        $nav.each( function( i ) {

                            $( this ).on( 'click', function( event ) {

                                var $dot = $( this );

                                if( !slitslider.isActive() ) {

                                    $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                                    $dot.addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );

                                }

                                slitslider.jump( i + 1 );
                                return false;

                            } );

                        } );

                    };

                    return { init : init };

            })();

            Page.init();

        });


    </script>
 <!--- END LINKS FOR PP_slider --->       


</head>
    <body class="cw"> 

        <!--- Server Side Include for the site header --->
        <?php include('_cw4-tmplt-ft1_header-include.php');?>

        <!--- Server Side Include for pp_slider --->
        <?php include('_cw4-tmplt-ft1_pp_slider-include.php');?>

        <?php
        // CARTWEAVER INCLUDE: product details 
        include("cw4/cw-productlist.php");
        ?>

    </body> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cw4/js/showhide.js"></script>
    <script src="cw4/js/styleswitch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</html
```

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that your select box causes a postback (submit), therefore reloading the page?

Comment: I'm afraid i have no idea (i am fairly new to php and js) but i assume that it would recall the required products from the database and cause the page to reload, obviously the slider takes time to reload and so it all slows down.

Comment: The majority of sites will have similar issues where the page is "reset" when you change an option.  Unless you fancy diving into learning how to use AJAX then you may just have to accept it.  Look at this site and see how everything loads, without the page reloading, when you change options and click update... http://www.scubapursuits.com/BCDs-D100400

Comment: here is a link to an image showing the page if it helps at all... http://www.judithdecorti.co.uk/page_image.png

Comment: I totally understand the problem.  The page reloads every time you change the dropdown value.  You want it to load the products without doing a full page reload.  You need AJAX for that, which is going to mean knowing a lot more php and Javascript, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you Archer, i really appreciate the input. If i had somebody who knew AJAX sat next to me now how long do you think it would take them to fix this? As i may get the rest of the site done and call somebody in to fix it.

Comment: You'll need an all-rounder to help you with this.  They'd need to write a Javascript method that makes AJAX calls, as well as a PHP handler to get and return the data.  I can't say for sure how long it would take, but it could be as little as a few hours, or as much as a few days.  It depends on too many variables.  Do you have a link to the actual page, or is it not public?

Comment: No it's all local at the moment i'm afraid. I guess i'll have to start saving some serious money! Ouch.

Comment: It *may* be possible to do it all in Javascript, loading the page in memory and parsing it for the changed elements and posting them to the page.  I could only say for sure if I could see it.  This would be quicker than writing the whole thing, but not the "best" way of doing it.

Comment: Thats the kind of way i'd hoped for. Maybe i can try and get it online over the next 48hrs and post back?

Comment: By all means - I'll happily have a look at it if you can :)

Comment: That would be such a help, thanks again :)